# Need to avoid Digital Signature Public certificate BinarySecurityElement from being mtom encoded

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ws-security, mtom

I am faced with an issue that I cannot seem to resolve. Consuming a java based web service using wcf and ws security. Using non-mtom requests, the public key certificate gets sent as part of the binarysecurityelement as a base64 string. However the same certificate is mtom-encoded for mtom requests. Is there a way I can avoid that using wcf so that the public key certificate gets sent as an embedded base 64 string within the binarysecurityelement and not as a multipart section beneath the soap request envelope?

This is happening for a certificate with public key is an RSA (2048 bits) and works fine for a certificate with public key : RSA (1024 bits)

So with the certificate having RSA 2048 bit public key something like below is happening:

```
<o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-4d4ee765-5717-4d53-9ac9-99bddc07df6c-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">
        <xop:Include href="cid:http%3A%2F%2Ftempuri.org%2F1%2F632618206525089430" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
      </o:BinarySecurityToken>
```

Instead I need the base64 certificate value embedded instead of the xop:include element. Which happens correctly for my certificate having RSA 1024 bit Public Key.

I have a custom encoder in place as well to write the message, but I cannot seem to find any specific method to override which will allow me to modify how binarysecurity token is generated in the request. Thoughts?

Not sure if custom encoder will help here too, invoked writemessage on the message object using an xmlwriter to a file. I can see the binarysecuritytoken comprising of a base64 string which I believe is the certificate raw bytes. Its probably after that the message is mtom optimized?

Comment: Is there any specific size setting that I can set, so that only data size > threshhold value gets mtom encoded?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an easy way here. You could disable MTOM all together but otehrwise it will optimize binary data. It has an internal threashold which I don't think you can configure (it is cost effective to move binary data out of the message only from certain size).

If you want to try this anyway then you would probably need to implement a [custom message encoder](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/11/09/wcf-extensibility-message-encoders.aspx) which is very similar to the MTOM encoder (so look at it code in reflector) and maybe you can even call it internally. What you want to replace is the instantiation of the XmlMtomWriter. In your own writer overide the writeBase64() method such that it will delegate to writeString if the data has not passed the threashold. You could do a dry run of this whole scenario by having .Net in source debug mode and putting breakpoints at the right spots.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think Instead of going the threshhold route I am following a different approach here. I already have a custom encoder class inheriting from MessageEncoder. Within this class I have overridden the WriteMessage method. Internally the method calls the innerencoder writemessage method and the output is then modified to replace the xop:includ with the base64 version of the certificate raw bytes(Using regex to replace the xop:include part) Not sure if this is an elegant solution or not but seems to be working :)